# Show that every formula of propositional logic except atoms has unique formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to show :

Every formula of propositional logic A except atoms can be written uniquely to one of these formulas $(B\wedge C)$,$(B \vee C)$ ,$(B \rightarrow C)$ or $(\neg B)$ which $B,C$ are propositional logic.

I tried to prove this by induction on the length of A.

Base case : I suppose A has minimum length ,because A is proposition and is not atom so it should be $(p_1 \wedge p_2)$ or $(p_1 \vee p_2)$ or $(p_1 \rightarrow p_2)$ or $(\neg p_1)$ and $p_i$ are atoms but I don't have any idea that A is unique.

Induction hypotheses:

Suppose $A_1,A_2$ are propositional logics that can be written uniquely to $(B_1\wedge C_1)$,$(B_1 \vee C_1)$ ,$(B_1 \rightarrow C_1)$ or $(\neg B)$  .

Now I don't know how to show that if $A = (A_1 \vee A_2 )$,it is unique formula for $A$.

If I don't prove with induction if I suppose that $A = (...(A_1o_1A_2)o_3(A_3o_3A_4)o_4...A_k)...)$ which $o_i \in \{\wedge,\vee,\rightarrow\}$ and $A_i = p_i \;or\; A_i = (\neg p_i)$ for $i = 1 ... k$ and $p_i$ are atoms now I don't know how to continue!!

Can anyone help me to prove this?

Comment: I don't know what decomposed means.  What text are you studying?

Comment: I mean that $A = (B \vee C)$ or $A= B \wedge C$ or $A= B \rightarrow C$ or $A = \neg B$ uniquely.

Comment: What do you mean by 'uniquely'?

Comment: Also, it is certainly not true that any propositional logic statement (that is not atomic) is equivalent to $B \vee C$, $B \wedge C$, $B \rightarrow C$, or $\neg B$: what about a statement like $D \wedge E$?  So I suppose that $B$ and $C$ are seen as variables, meaning that the claim is that every statement can be written as a conjunction, disjunction, conditional, or negation?  But *that* would be trivial: every statement $P$ is equivalent to $P \vee (Q \wedge \neg Q)$, so yes, every statement can be written as a disjunction.  So I guess I just don't understand the question!

Comment: It states that every statement can be written as a cunjunctin,disconjunction,conditional or negation uniquely,it means that you can't write a statement in  2 different negation statement.